# Mean of log-normal variable when exponent is replaced by runnung maximum of Ito-integral

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $W=\{W_t\}_{t\in[0;1]}$ be a real-valued Brownian motion, $\{F_t\}_{t\in [0;1]}$ the filtration generated by $W$, augmented with the nullsets. Let $\{\sigma_t\}_{t\in[0;1]}$ be a continuous and bounded Ito process (**EDIT**: w.r.t. $W$) with bounded drift and volatility coefficients (I could also live with more restrictions). I want to prove that
\begin{align*}
A
:=
\mathbb E\bigg( \exp\bigg( \sup_{t\in[0;1]}\int^t_0 \sigma_s \mathrm dW_s\bigg) \bigg)
<
\infty.
\end{align*}

If $\sigma$ was constant, this would be obvious since the distribution of the running maximum of the Brownian motion is known and the above expectation can be computed in closed integral form.

**Question:** Any ideas how to bound $A$ in a more general case than "$\sigma$ constant"? Or can such a result be found in the literature? Thank you!

This question has been [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477916) on math.stackexchange a few days ago, but got no answers so far. (The "partially solved" in the title refers to the fact that meanwhile I managed to bound $B$ (see below), which was not the case when I asked the question on math.stackexchange originally. Thus, I have edited the question there. The main problem to bound $A$ is still unsolved.)

**What I have tried:** As an easier exercise, first I tried to prove the following:
\begin{align*}
B
:=
\mathbb E\bigg( \exp\bigg( \int^1_0 \sigma_s \mathrm dW_s\bigg) \bigg)
<
\infty.
\end{align*}
This is also easy since the stochastic exponential is a martingale and then
\begin{align*}
1
=&
\mathbb E\bigg( \exp\bigg(
  \int^1_0 \sigma_s \mathrm dW_s
  - \frac 1 2 \int^1_0 (\sigma_s)^2 \mathrm ds
\bigg) \bigg)
\\\ge&
\mathbb E\bigg( \exp\bigg(
  \int^1_0 \sigma_s \mathrm dW_s
\bigg) \bigg)
e^{- \frac 1 2 \Vert \sigma\Vert^2}
\\=&
B e^{- \frac 1 2 \Vert \sigma\Vert^2}.
\end{align*}

Moreover, I thought we could $L^2$-approximate the Ito integral by
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_{(k-1)/n} ( W_{k/n} - W_{(k-1)/n} ),
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to approximate the supremum and anyway we cannot pull $L^2$-convergence into the $\exp$ function because $\exp$ increases faster than $\operatorname{id}^2$.

Comment: Your computation is suspicious since $\|\sigma\|_2^2$ is a random variable....

Comment: By $\Vert \sigma\Vert \in \mathbb R$, I mean a uniform (in $(\omega,s)$) bound on the value of $\sigma_s(\omega)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This edit reflects the actual question asked, and corrects an earlier answer.

You can rewrite the process $\int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s$ as a time change of Brownian motion, where the time change is given by $\tau(t)=\int_0^{t} \sigma^2(s) ds$.
If $\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |\sigma_t|<R$ a.s. for some deterministic $R$, then $\tau(1)\leq R^2$. Then
$$ E(e^{\sup_{t\in [0,1]}\int_0^t W_s ds})
=E(e^{\sup_{t\in [0,1]} B_{\tau(t)} })
\leq E(e^{\sup_{u\in [0,R^2]} B_{u}})<\infty$$
by the reflection principle.

In the more general case, where $\tau(1)$ is not uniformly bounded,
define $A_t= {\int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s}$ and $B_t={\frac12 \int_0^t \sigma_s^2 ds}$. Fix $\alpha\in (0,1)$.
If the condition $E(e^{2\tau(1)/\alpha^2})=E(e^{4 B_1/\alpha^2})<\infty$ holds then
$$M_t= e^{2A_t/\alpha -(4/\alpha^2)B_t}$$
is a (positive) martingale, by Novikov's criterion, up to $t=1$,
and in particular
$E(\sup_{t\in [0,1]} M_t^{\alpha})<\infty$ by Doob's inequality. Now,
\begin{eqnarray}
E(\sup_{t\in[0,1]} e^{A_t})&\leq & E(\sup_{t\in [0,1]} e^{A_t-2B_t/\alpha} e^{2B_1/\alpha})\\
&\leq& (E(\sup_{t\in [0,1]} M_t^{\alpha}))^{1/2} (E(e^{4B_1/\alpha}))^{1/2}<\infty,
\end{eqnarray}
where the second inequality used Cauchy-Schwarz and the definition of $M_t$.

Comment: What is the "tail" of a stochastic process? And by "endpoint" you mean the random variable corresponding to the largest possible time index?

Comment: Tail is $P(X>x)$ for $x$ large, which is all you care about when computing $E(e^X)$. Recall that the tail of the distribution of the maximum of BM on an interval $[0,T}$ is just twice that of the distribution  of the BM at time $T$ (as I wrote, this follows from the reflection principle).

Comment: If (as you asked) $\tau(1)$ is bounded, say by a deterministc $A$, then $\sup_{t\in[0,1]} B_{\tau(t)}\leq \sup_{s\in [0,A]} B_s$.